# Create a new struct with reflect from type defined by a nil pointer

Tags: reflection, go

I would like know if it is possible to allocate a struct from a type specified by a `nil` pointer by using `reflect.New()`

```
type SomeType struct{
   A int
}

sometype := (*SomeType)(nil)

v := reflect.valueOf(sometype)
// I would like to allocate a new struct based on the type defined by the pointer
// newA := reflect.New(...)
//
newA.A = 3
```

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`reflect.Type.Elem()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type):

```
s := (*SomeType)(nil)
t := reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()

v := reflect.New(t)
sp := (*SomeType)(unsafe.Pointer(v.Pointer()))
sp.A = 3
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Qq8eo-W2yq

**EDIT**: Elwinar in comments below pointed out that you can get the struct without `unsafe.Pointer` by using `reflect.Indirect()`:

```
s := (*SomeType)(nil)
t := reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()

ss := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(t)).Interface().(SomeType)
ss.A = 3
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/z5xgEMR_Vx

Comment: Is it the only possibility ? Is there a way without using the unsafe package ?

Comment: To prevent having to use the `unsafe` package, you should use the `reflect.Indirect` method. One-liner : `reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(sometype).Elem())).Interface().(SomeType)`

Comment: Is it the same operation to proceed but starting with an interface ? I mean you have an object A implementing the I interface. I start from the interface I and I would like to create the same underlying object that implement the interface I using reflect ?